# Ubuntu 18.04/10, 19.04 using Thinkpad dock - mouse clicks don't work

Tags: 18.04, mouse, thinkpad, 19.04, dock

Using a thinkpad t460s docked with ubuntu 18.04 is almost perfect. The quirk is that when I plug in to the dock, the mouse clicks stop working - this is a dual monitor setup and the laptop lid is closed. When I open the lid (now 3 screens) mouse clicks work. Close the lid, no click. Weird right!?!

Thinking it could be solved with newer kernal, I upgraded to 18.10. Nope. Then 19.04. YES! It worked... for a week.

No amount of unpluging, port switching, modprobing, (un)suspending or restarting has got us back to that glorious first week of Disco.

I also have not been able to crack the search phrase to get me towards a solution.

Appreciative of any pointers.

Comment: Should point out that I have also tried wired usb, wireless usb (w/dongle) and wireless bluetooth mice. All exhibit the same behavior.